# Binary files with Struct, classes, fstream error

Tags: c++, function, class, struct, fstream

i have a question regarding a assignment i have.

here i have 2 of the classes, employee class and gm class

```
void GM::addEmployee(fstream& afile, int noOfRecords)
{
    afile.open("EmployeeInfo.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);   
        employee::eInfo e;
        employee emp;
    char name[80];
    cout << "\nAdd Employee Info" << endl;
    cout << "---------------------" << endl;
    cout << "New Employee Username: ";
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    cin.getline(name, 80);
        //Check if there is already an entry inside the file with this name.
        //If yes, add fail
    bool flag = true;
    if(noOfRecords > 0)
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=noOfRecords; i++)
        {   
            afile.read (reinterpret_cast <char *>(&e), sizeof(e));
            if(!strcmp(name, e.username))
            {
                cout << "Username is used, add GM failed" << endl;
                flag = false;
            }
        }

    } 
    afile.close();

        if(flag)
        {
             //open in appending mode
             afile.open("EmployeeInfo.dat", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
             strcpy(e.username, name);
             cout << "Please Enter New Employee's Password: ";
             cin.getline(e.password, 80);
             cout << "\nPlease Enter New Employee's Appointment "
                  << "\n(0 = GM / 1 = HM / "
                  << "2= BS / 3 = FOS)\n : ";
             cin >> e.eid;
             cin.clear();
             cin.ignore(100, '\n');
             emp.dist = strlen(e.password);
             emp.caesar_encrypt(e.password, 3, emp.dist);
             afile.write(reinterpret_cast <const char *>(&e), sizeof(e));
         afile.close();

             cout << "\nEmployee Added" << endl;
        }

}
```

The above is a function from my GM class, which is to add employees.

i have declared a structure in employee class as

```
struct eInfo
{
    char username [80];
    char password [80];
    int eid;
};
```

The problem with this way of doing, is that when i try to add employee
my EmployeeInfo.dat data disappears. everything becomes blank after i used the add employee function.

can anyone guide me on what i did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong way to read data into `e`:

> ```
> afile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&e), sizeof(e));
> ```

Likewise, this is the wrong way to write data from `e`:

> ```
> afile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&e), sizeof(e));
> ```

If you need to print or read the data members of `e`, you need to do so one at a time. Moreover, using `read`/`write` in this context is unecessary because you simply use the extractor and inserter:

> ```
> afile >> e.username;
> // ...
> afile << e.username << e.password;
> ```

Comment: I am not proficient with C, but is it necessary to pass the afile object to this function?

Comment: @bf2020 Is it necessary to pass `afile` to *what* function? Sorry, I don't seem to follow... BTW this is *C++*.

Comment: Don't worry, it's me that's not following...  A bad question on my part.  I don't know _C++_ and am confused by what `::` is used for on the first line.  I'll read up on it.

Comment: @bf2020 Oh, now I see what you're saying - `::` is the scope resolution operator. We are using it in this context to define a method named `addEmployee` from the `GM` class. `afile` is a file stream object being passed to the function. It's necessary in the sense that we need it to write to and read from the file. Hypothetically, we could've created the file stream object in the function definition, but that would confine the `addEmoloyee` method to only read from/write to a *specific* file. It's nice to give the caller of the function a choice in what file they would like to pass.